# Apache NiFi Spring Boot integration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-nifi

Understand that Apache NiFi could integrate with Spring as shown in [SpringOne Platform 2016 Replay: Spring with ApacheNiFi](https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/13/springone-platform-2016-replay-spring-with-apachenifi). NiFi uses [SpringContextProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-spring-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor/) to load Spring XML application context.

Question: Could NiFi integrate with Spring Boot? Specifically, could NiFi processor flows to a processor which calls a Spring Boot app, and then flows back to a NiFi processor? If so, is there any sample to demonstrate it?

Note: This integration is NOT about NiFi calling a Spring Boot REST API as shown in [Spring Boot 2.0 on ACID : Integrating REST Microservices with Apache NiFi](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/177256/spring-boot-20-on-acid-integrating-rest-microservi.html).

Comment: Looking at [nifi-spring-bundle](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/rel/nifi-1.7.1/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-spring-bundle/nifi-spring-processors) source code, NiFi doesn't support Spring Boot, but supports Spring. SpringContextDelegate uses ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load Spring XML configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: This integration is NOT about NiFi calling a Spring Boot REST API as shown in Spring Boot 2.0 on ACID : Integrating REST Microservices with Apache NiFi.

REST is the only integration pattern here between Spring Boot apps and NiFi. The processor your referenced is good for using Spring components, but Spring Boot itself is a full application framework and would take a significant amount of effort to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

The Nifi flow could use the [InvokeHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/) processor to call a REST API which is implemented as your spring boot application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this Processor. SpringContextProcessor.

> SpringContextProcessor – allows integration of processes encapsulated
> in Spring Application Context to run as NiFi processor by becoming a
> runtime host for an instance of Spring Application Context.

[There is a demo video. It's very helpful](https://youtu.be/F98NLule18I?t=1691)

[Official Apache Nifi SpringContextProcessor Documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-spring-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor/additionalDetails.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.